# my js has some problems, it is jumping from $.widget to return $.devall.popupmanager and fail function is getting called at the end

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, jquery, popup

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
    'mage/cookies'
], function ($, modal) {
    'use strict';

    if(!$.cookie('popup_cookie') ) {

        $.widget('devall.popupManager', {

             /**
             *
             * @private
             */

            _create: function () {
                var self = this,
                    popup_newsletter_options = {
                        type: 'popup',
                        responsive: true,
                        innerScroll: true,
                        title: this.options.popupTitle,
                        buttons: false,
                        modalClass: 'popup-devnewsletter'
                    };
                var expDate = new Date();

                expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime() + (3650000 * 60 * 1000));
                $.cookie('popup_cookie', 1, {expires: expDate});

                modal(popup_newsletter_options, this.element);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    self._setStyleCss();
                    self.element.modal('openModal');
                }, 3000);
                this.element.find('form').submit(function () {
                    if ($(this).validation('isValid')) {
                        console.log("Hello 1!");
                        $.ajax({
                            url: $(this).attr('action'),
                            cache: true,
                            data: $(this).serialize(),
                            dataType: 'json',
                            type: 'POST',
                            showLoader: true,
                        }).done(function (data) {
                            console.log("Hello 2!");

                            self.element.find('.popup-manager .messages').html(data.message);
                            if (data.error) {
                                self.element.find('.messages .message').addClass('message-error error');
                                self.element.modal('closeModal');
                                self.element.find('.messages .message').addClass('message-success success');
                                // var cookieExpires = new Date(new Date().getTime() + this.options.cookieLifetime * 1000);

                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    self.element.modal('closeModal');
                                }, 1000);
                            }
                            self.element.find('.messages').show();

                            setTimeout(function () {
                                self.element.find('.messages').hide();
                            }, 5000);
                        }).fail(function (data) {
                            alert("Error");
                        })

                    }
                    return false;
                });


                this._resetStyleCss();
            },

            /**
             * Set width of the popup
             * @private
             */
            _setStyleCss: function (width) {

                width = width || 400;

                if (window.innerWidth > 786) {
                    this.element.parent().parent('.modal-inner-wrap').css({'max-width': width + 'px'});
                }
            },

            /**
             * Reset width of the popup
             * @private
             */
            _resetStyleCss: function () {
                var self = this;
                $(window).resize(function () {
                    if (window.innerWidth <= 786) {
                        self.element.parent().parent('.modal-inner-wrap').css({'max-width': 'initial'});
                    } else {
                        self._setStyleCss(self.options.innerWidth);
                    }
                });
            },

        });


        return $.devall.popupManager;
    }

    return 0;

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

action had no argument, I was calling $block->getacctionurl() instead of $viewmodel->getacctionurl();

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/168522)

Comment: actually I am an author as well.

Comment: Got that. You can add detail answer here If issue is sorted out and if this is just an update then i would suggest to edit the question. Good luck.